# GetDIBits выдаёт неверные пиксели

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь вытянуть из совместного битмапа(полностью заполнен `RGB(0,0,255)`) массив пикселей через `GetDIBits`, но выдаются какие-то другие цвета. А при попытке внести изменения в массив, вообще вылетает. Что не так?

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    HBRUSH hb = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));

    HDC hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, r.right, r.bottom);

    SelectObject(hdcc, bm);
    SelectObject(hdcc, hb);

    Rectangle(hdcc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom); //зарисовываю синей кистью

    BITMAPINFO bi = { 0 };

    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);

    int er = GetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, 0, NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    //В GetDIBits в качестве HDC должен же совместный выступать, да?

    if (!er)
    {
        cout << "ERROR HERE:"<< GetLastError()<<"ENDS";
    }

    COLORREF *buf = new COLORREF(bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage); \\Так и не понял какого типа должен быть массив - char, BYTE, COLORREF или какой-то ещё

    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = abs(bi.bmiHeader.biHeight);

    GetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, buf, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    for (int i(0); i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << (int)GetRValue(buf[i]) << ",";
        cout << (int)GetGValue(buf[i]) << ",";
        cout << (int)GetBValue(buf[i]) << ",";
        cout << endl;
    }

    SetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, buf, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    delete []buf;

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom, hdcc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(hb);
    DeleteDC(hdcc);
    DeleteObject(bm);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После первого вызова `GetDIBits` нам становится известны размеры битмапа (хотя тут они известны заранее). Затем можно посчитать размер требуемого буфера (`biSizeImage` может быть 0 или не совпадать с требуемым размером буфера, если требуемый формат отличается от текущего) и выделить массив. При выделении массива у вас тоже ошибка - вы выделяете только один элемент, инициализируя его значением bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage.

```
auto const bitmap_pixels_count{::std::abs(bi.bmiHeader.biWidth * bi.bmiHeader.biHeight)};
COLORREF * buf = new COLORREF[bitmap_pixels_count]; // выделяем массив
```

Еще отмечу, что Rectangle рисует прямоугольник с обводкой текущим пером.